# Artisan::call('migrate') error in multi-tenant app: Database hosts array is empty

Tags: laravel, mariadb, multi-tenant

I'm building a Laravel multi-tenant application (running MariaDB 10.4.13) and am stuck where I need to switch databases and run migrations for a new tenant. Based on my research, I could come up with this code for changing database connections for a tenant:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $tenant->main_db_host);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $tenant->main_db_database);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $tenant->main_db_username);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $tenant->main_db_password);
DB::purge('mysql');
DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

I tested this piece of code in the Tinker console by saying `DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()` which prints the expected name, so I have to guess this part is "working".

The problem is when I add a call to `Artisan::call('migrate');` to sync the database schema. This gives me the error:

```
Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I'm just not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Where  you want to use these peice of code? In the controller or in the command or in the terminal of server?

Comment: @ChintanMirani In the controller, since a new tenant can register anytime and they should be able to use the app right away.

Comment: @ChintanMirani Turns out it was my own oversight! Sorry for the trouble. Please see my answer below for the silly explanation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post my own answer and close this out as it was my own mistake. It's not clear from the code I posted because the order of function calls was different, but I was making the `migrate` call *before* the DB details were present on the Tenant model instance. After I shifted this call to the `$tenant->save()`, it worked as expected. Silly me. :(